# How can you make curved PLATED slot in Altium 17?

Tags: pcb, altium

I need to make a plated slot in Altium, but it needs to be CURVED, rather than straight. I can make non-plated curved cutout by drawing curved track with the needed thickness and then using Tools>Convert>Create Region/Cutout from selected primitives. But I cannot find a way to specify that this cutout should get plated.

Comment: Does the Tools>Convert>Create Region/Cutout feature have an option for which layer the feature ends up?  Basically, your curved track needs to end up on the same layer of the board as a straight slot would -- and your PCB manufacturer needs to like it, so consulting with them before you make it happen on a Gerber is a good thing.

Comment: Using Convert, the curved slot ends up on the board cutout layer, which should be okay as this is the layer used for routing the board outline. Okay, so far so good, but how do I make it plated? If you consider a straight plated slot or via they are both drawn using the "pad" tool and there you can tick the option "plated". But this is not an option for cutouts. Should I just place a comment for the fab that it needs to be plated and let them sort it out.